# WARNING message on a summit extreme router

Tags: router

I have a Summit extreme router and I've recently been receiving the following error:

```
<WARN:ESRP> edp.c 2892: PREMASTER-->Master : VLAN=Buyers1 [HIGHER Priority]
<WARN:ESRP> edp.c 2780: MASTER-->slave : VLAN=Buyers1 [Master PDU in master state]
<WARN:RIP > ripDeleteRt: SIOCDELRT (S_objLib_OBJ_TIMEOUT)
```

It's giving the first two errors on every vlan I have.

My entire network usually starts to lose connectivity. The only thing that has changed lately is someone put a NAT policy on our firewall to point to a 192.168.225.x IP address. Would this cause this error? Also, what does the error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These messages are because the master was failing over to the slave switch. The slave switch was sending out tons of TX errors. I'm thinking the slave was sending out bad ESRP request too, making the master look like it was failing. The slave was sending out so many TX errors and that's the reason my network was losing connectivity.

I unhooked the slave and disabled ESRP. I've recently replaced both of the switches and stress level/power usage is down.

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://www.extremenetworks.com/libraries/services/ErrorMessageDecoderRev5.pdf

```
Failed to Delete RIP Route
ripExpireRt: SIOCDELRT (S_errno_EWOULDBLOCK)
Software Version
ExtremeWare 6.0 and later
Hardware Version
All
Explanation
The system failed to delete RIP route from the IP routing table. The RIP route to be deleted is not found
in the Kernel routing table.
Action
Verify whether the expired RIP route entry is present in the IP routing table.
If any invalid route entry is present, reboot the switch.
```

Comment: I read that last night. I undid the recent changes that were made to the network, and if this doesn't work I'm going to restart the router. Thanks.